# Problems when using RANKX on PowerPivot

Tags: mdx, powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to use the RANKX funcion to Rank some sales, my table looks like this

ProductID | ProductTotal |

I want to have a third column called ProductRank that will rank the The products depending on the ProductTotal, this is what I have

```
=RANKX(ALL('Query'[ProductID]),'Query'[ProductTotal])
```

However, this is nor working :(

any help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [ProductTotal] is a column then the following should work

```
=RANKX(ALL('Query'[ProductID]),CALCULATE(SUM('Query'[ProductTotal])))
```